# How to load the data based on count every few second interval in angular

Tags: angular

I have 4 objects into an array, I want to load/console 2 objects at a time only,then after 2 seconds again want to load remaining 2 objects..so on until I reached to 4, in angular. Here is the code below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5kbra1

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  arraydata = [
    { name: "name1", value: 1 },
    { name: "name2", value: 2 },
    { name: "name3", value: 3 },
    { name: "name4", value: 4 }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.arraydata);
  }
}
```

Comment: easiest way would be to use `setInterval`, you can also use an `Observable`: [interval](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval)

Comment: ok but how to get the next 2 objects every interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for but you could use RxJS `from` function to create a stream of objects and buffer and delay them using `concatMap`, `bufferCount` and `delay` operators.

Try the following

```js
from(this.arraydata)
  .pipe(
    bufferCount(2),
    concatMap(objs => of(objs).pipe(delay(2000)))
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: objs => {
      console.log(objs);
      // do something else
    }
  });
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5juvho?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

The one downside I see here that you didn't mention is the first emission will also be delayed 2 seconds.